# calling Javascript from java using ScriptEngine

Tags: javascript, java

i am trying to open the new tab from java itsself using scriptEngine.

```
private static void openWindow(URL url) {
    String javascript = "window.open(url, '_blank').focus()";
    ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("js");
    engine.put("url", url);
    try{
        engine.eval(javascript);
        }
    }
    catch(ScriptException exception){
        log4j.error("Couldn't open URL in Browser: " + exception.getMessage(), exception);

    }
}
```

i am getting following exception :

**javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "window" is not defined. (#1) in  at line number 1**

I understand windows cannot be referenced but what is the alternative here ?

Any pointers would be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

This piece of Java has no reference to a browser, hence the error saying that window is not defined.

In case you really want to interact with a browser from Java you might consider looking into Selenium Webdriver. This is often used for testing purposes but might fit your need also.

For opening a page see this [Selenium example](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#introducing-the-selenium-webdriver-api-by-example).